# OneToMany bidirectional mapping is not saving its foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one-to-many relationship between Employee & Phone entities like this:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();
}

@Entity
public class Phone {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String phoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID")
    private Employee owner;
}
```

In my code if I save phone first then employee next:

```
session.save(phone);
session.save(employee);
```

Then I am seeing and insert query to save Employee, then insert query to save Phone and then update query to update owner_id in Phone table.

So to avoid insert and update on Phone table, I have added below mapping in my Phone entity:

```
@Entity
public class Phone {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Employee owner;
}
```

Now in this case, I see insert on Employee then insert on Phone, but the owner_id is null.

How to make sure that the owner_id is not null when I save the entities? I want to save Phone then Employee in my code not the other way.

Answer (score 1):

As phone is a child entity, it will need reference of employee for saving. 
By annotating Phone with cascadeType, your phone will be saved with your employee  entity. Your modified entities will be like this :

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();

  /*getters and setters*/
}

@Entity
public class Phone {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String phoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false,nullable=false)
    private Employee owner;
    /*getters and setters*/

}
```

And have to modify your saving logic as below :

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();
Phone phone = new Phone();
phone.setOwner(emp);

phones.add(phone);

emp.setPhones(phones);

session.save(emp);
```

Comment: I don't want to use cascade here, you are saving employee, but I want to save Phone first then employee explicitly. So is it not possible with my approach?

Comment: @user3181365  I guess no, because you said that while saving phone you need `OWNER_ID` as not null field. In that case, `Phone` will not get saved first and will throw error as `OWNER_ID` is null. Therefore, employee must be saved first and then `phone`.

Comment: Wrongly I supposed to need to save employee twice to have its id in phones, but probably hibernate handles that for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, no need to use bidirectional. Try the following steps

1. Only need to declare `@ManyToOne` in Phone entity. So remove `@OneToMany` declaration from Employee entity.
2. Hibernate `session.save(obj)` returns the id of Object. So just save Phone first and catch `id` then save employee.See sample

   ```
    session.save(phone);
    long phoneOneId = phone.getId();
    Phone phoneOne = new Phone();
    phoneOne.setId(phoneOneId);
    // You can also add another phone like phoneTwo, phoneThree, ...
    List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();
    phones.add(phoneOne);
    employee.setPhones(phones);
   ```